# Параметризация дружественной функции

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Как в `A` объявить дружественную функцию с параметром типа `A` и реализацией вне класса?

```
template <typename t_A> class A
{  
   public:
     friend ostream& operator << (ostream &os, A const &s); // <-- ошибка
};

ostream& operator << (ostream &os, A const &s) // <-- ошибка
{
};
```

Comment: класса А уже нету. Есть только шаблонный класс А с шаблонным типом, что вы укажете

Comment: @rikimaru2013 Я это понимаю. Как правильно написать?

Comment: @ixSci Согласен

Comment: @ixSci А если я не могу вынести реализацию до класса?